# Set up multiple vendors in Prestashop Store

Tags: prestashop

I need to set up multiple vendors in my prestashop store. Can i have different levels of vendors , example Vendor 1 will be able to list only 100 products, level 2 vendor will be able to list 200 products. I found this link by researching 
http://www.addons-modules.com/prestashop-tips/prestashop-multiple-seller-multiple-vendor-module/

Is this possible with Agile multiple seller module?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use this module and agile membership module together to implement your requirements. the 2 modules have been integrated together.

Comment: Should be in comment.